# How to get URL connection using proxy in java?

Tags: java, url, proxy, connection

I am trying to create URL connection using a proxy at run time. My code is below:

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("192.0.2.100", 80));
HttpURLConnection connection =
    (HttpURLConnection)new URL("http://abc.example.com").openConnection(proxy);
```

But this is not working. Anybody know why?

Comment: What is not working? Do you get a StackTrace or an error?

Comment: Why is it not working? What is the error?

Comment: What type of proxy are you using?

Comment: Thank you guys it worked. i needed to configure connection request. connection.setDoOutput(true);
  connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "text/xml");
  connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/xml, application/xml");
  connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

Comment: You can and should post your solution as an answer to this question(which you can accept later).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

adding answer for the help of future visitors

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("192.0.2.100", 80));
HttpURLConnection connection =(HttpURLConnection)new URL("http://abc.example.com").openConnection(proxy);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "text/xml");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/xml, application/xml");
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
```

Comment: Thank you @dku.rajkumar , how can i set user and password here ?

Answer (score 3):

*dku.rajkumar*'s way doesn't work with me.

I try this and it work. But it takes double time.

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("192.0.2.100", 80));

    HttpURLConnection connection =
        (HttpURLConnection)new URL("http://abc.example.com").openConnection(proxy);
    ((HttpURLConnection)new URL("http://abc.example.com").openConnection(proxy)).getInputStream();

System.out.println(connection.usingProxy());
```

the result is true

without 
`((HttpURLConnection)new URL("http://abc.example.com").openConnection(proxy)).getInputStream();`

the result is false