# System.setProperty working undesirably

Tags: java, url, networking, system

I am beginner in Network Programming.
here is my very simple code:

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost","127.0.0.1");
URL url=new URL("http:\\www.google.com");
url.openConnection();   // Connection object is getting returned
```

My question is - 
If I am providing the proxy setting still my program is making direct connection with host . Why?

Comment: Atleast leave a comment why a down vote. So I can understand my mistake

Comment: Please help anybody. Cannot resume my study prior of understanding this concept.

Comment: setting system property will not make it a proxy in java. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148024/how-to-get-url-connection-using-proxy-in-java#8561366) one for doing it the right way

Answer (score 1):

Having a read of the Java API Documentation for URL, there is no mention that setting a system property as you have would make any difference.

The documentation does make mention of another method, which may be what you're after.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openConnection(java.net.Proxy)

Additionally, your URL string should contain forward slashes rather than backslashes.

```
"http://www.google.com"
```

Comment: The properties are documented here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html